# Unable to pass table type as parameter inside Canvas app

Tags: powerapps

I have this method called in a custom connector which takes a parameter "project name" which is a string and a parameter in body "assetIds" which is of array kind [12322,22332].  and I am able to validate and call successfully when testing it in the connector. I tried to call inside the app using  this using this formulae.

```
customconnectorname.FilterEvents("myprojectname",{assetIds:[
5884566067180248,
4000106819215821
]})
```

and I get error as datasource *expects string* and you are passing Table. so I changed and passed something like this

```
customconnectorname.FilterEvents("myprojectname",{assetIds:5884566067180248})
```

and now I get error *data source Expected Table* . I would like to know how should I pass this ? what is the correct way of passing the value. In connector this is how I pass and it works:

[image]

Method declaration

[image]

```
PATH PARAMETERS
project
required
string


QUERY PARAMETERS
assetIds    
string <jsonArray(int64)> (JsonArrayInt64)
Example: assetIds=[363848954441724, 793045462540095, 1261042166839739]
Asset IDs of equipment that this event relates to. Format is list of IDs serialized as JSON array(int64). Takes [ 1 .. 100 ] of unique items.
```

Here is the swagger definition from PowerApps. the assetsId part is :

```
assetIds:
                type: array
                items: {type: integer, format: int32}
                description: assetIds
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your method declaration?

Comment: updated. do you need any other details

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried instead of passing [ id, id, id ], do "[id, id, id]"?

Comment: yes I did it didnt work

Comment: If you open the connector in swagger mode, you should see if the action indeed expects an array or a string. I guess your declaration went wrong, Like Groger mentioned.

Comment: please check the question. i have updated the method. and I am trying with both table and text and it fails in both. It works in test page where I manually pass the assetsId

Comment: The server can expect for example /?id=1&id=2, or /?id=[1,2,3] or other forms. Check the documentation of the API you are calling to see what it is expecting with multiple Id's.

Comment: i provided that snippet from documentation what is required in assetsId parameter. check the question

Comment: in swagger definition its something like this  assetIds:
                type: array
                items: {type: integer, format: int32}
                description: assetIds

Comment: I recreated the connector with some calls, but when I try to recreate the call with an array as filter it gives this warning in top:

Your custom connector has been successfully created, but there was an issue converting it to WADL for Power Apps: An error occured while converting OpenAPI file to WADL file. Error: 'Parameter with type='array' is not currently supported at JSON path paths['/api.contoso.com/api/projects/{project}/events'].get.parameters[1]'

I think sending an entire array as such is not supported in PowerApps. (Testing the custom connector is different from running the app.

Comment: i created from blank and didnt get any error on WADL file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242393/discussion-between-iona-varga-and-zzzsharepoint).